# Lenz' law in magnetohydrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, magnetohydrodynamics

I was wondering, is the Lorentz force tendency to oppose fluid motions just a manifestation of Lenz' law? Especially in dynamo problems where fluid motions induce the magnetic field.